# Creating a new folder in finder doesn't highlight "untitled folder" for renaming

Tags: finder

I have a trivial but annoying finder bug and I'm wondering if I am the only one?

If I hit **command-shift-N** in Finder to create a new folder it should automatically highlight the default name **untitled folder** ready for renaming. It works as expected in **icon** and **list** views but not **column view** which is really annoying because I use column view all the time. I am running OS X 10.8.4 (12E55).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works normally on my installation of 10.8.4, or ⇧⌘N also selects the untitled folder in column view.

You could try temporarily moving `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` somewhere else and relaunching Finder. Or quit background applications or try it on different account.

Comment: Trashing the .plis file did the trick, thanks Lauri